# PHP escape stored procedure param

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have litle problem with stored procedure when assign parameter value.
Am assigning value as a date `'2016-05-01','2016-07-30'`

Procedure work fine when i manual enter date like this:

```
CALL calculateSeasonPrice(3, '2016-05-01','2016-07-30')
```

success return array with data.

But problem is when i assign variables as arguments

```
$carId = 3;
$sDate = '2016-05-01';
// and
$eDate = '2016-07-30';

$price = $db->query("CALL calculateSeasonPrice({$carID},{$sDate},{$eDate})"); // problem
```

**return empty array**

Does i need to escape this two variales. I also try this and not work!

```
$price = $db->query("CALL calculateSeasonPrice(".$carID.",".$sDate.",".$eDate.")"); // This work
```

What i miss here?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php to your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the queries where you try to use variables you're forgetting the quotes for the values:

```
$price = $db->query("CALL calculateSeasonPrice('$carID','$sDate','$eDate')");
```

---

If you used [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements you would not have these kinds of problems. You can learn more about prepared statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

PDO Example:

```
$carId = 3;
$sDate = '2016-05-01';
$eDate = '2016-07-30';

$price = "CALL calculateSeasonPrice(?,?,?)";
$queryResults = $dbh->prepare($price);
$queryResults->execute(array($carId, $sDate, $eDate));
```

MySQLi Example:

```
$price = "CALL calculateSeasonPrice(?,?,?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("iss", $carId, $sDate, $eDate);
$stmt->execute();
```

Fundamentally these are not very different, but there are some subtle elements that you'll want to get used to, depending on the API you choose for your work.